Memory issue with micropython on development board
After downloading the STM32F407Disc firmware code from the micropython official website and compiling it with gcc, the micropython writing memory on the development board is only 95kb, which is not enough. I want to expand the memory. How can I solve this problem?
I hope it can be solved.

What do you mean with "micropython writing memory"? And not enough for what?

95kB for the Python filesystem is the expected amount of free space for the standard Micro Python build. See the end of this post.
If you need more space, you will need to either customise the featureset of your micro python or add external flash memory to get more filesystem space.

OK, thanks for your answer
